# How to move files to the TopParent folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm facing a problem with my code. It's only partially working.

My goal is to associate inside a dictionary the key (my file) with a value (the top level parent).

So, for FILE 2,3,4&5 , i want to associate the value 'FILE2'
But right now, the key 'FILE5' has the value 'FILE4' and not'FILE2.

```
{'FILE': 'FILE', 'FILE2': 'FILE2', 'FILE8': 'FILE8', 'FILE9': 'FILE9', 'FILE2': 'FILE12', 'FILE3': 'FILE2', 'FILE10': 'FILE9', 'FILE13': 'FILE12', 'FILE4': 'FILE2', 'FILE1': 'FILE9', 'FILE5': 'FILE4'}
```

I think i'm missing something with a recursion. But i don't know how to solve it.

[image: Excel sheet]

```
def FunctionD(item, dico):
    '''Create a dictionary where UltimateParent is key and value'''
    dico[item] = item


def FunctionE(child, parent, dico,dico2):
    '''Create a dictionary to assign the UltimateParent to some Children. If parent is key, we assign the parent as a value.'''
    '''/!\Here is the problem I think'''
    if parent in dico2 :
        dico[child] = parent
    if parent in dico2.values():
        dico[child] = dico[parent]



def FunctionA(path_src, path_dest, path_excel) :
    ''' Main fonction'''

    flag = input('Do you want the files sort by UltimateParent, by Reviewer or by Responsiveness ? (any key/Rw/Rp)')

    '''Read the Excel sheet and store it into a dataframe'''
    excel_file =path_excel
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    A = df.iloc[:,0].tolist() #ColumnA
    B = df.iloc[:,1].tolist() #ColumnB

    '''Try of assign the correct Ultimate Parent for each File'''
    dico ={}
    [FunctionD(i,dico) for i,j in zip(A,B) if isinstance(j, float)] #Dic Parents
    dico2 = dico.copy()
    [FunctionE(i, j, dico,dico2) for i, j in zip(A, B) if not isinstance(j, float)] #Associe parents et enfants (sf petitsenfants)
    dico3 =dico.copy()
    [FunctionE(i, j, dico, dico3) for i, j in zip(A, B) if not isinstance(j, float)] # Associe enfant aux parents
    dico4 = dico.copy()
    [FunctionE(i, j, dico, dico4) for i, j in zip(A, B) if not isinstance(j, float)]

    '''Creation of the UltimateParent folder'''
    [FunctionB(path_dest, i) for i,j in zip(A,B) if isinstance(j, float)] #creation des dossiers des parents
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to flatten directory tree by moving all files to root folder? what is that dict with "ELM" s? Can you please add a little description for your current code?

Comment: I want to create a dictionary where the keys are my files and the value the Top Level Parent.

Comment: For exemple, File5 is a child of File4. But file4 are a child of file3. Finally, File 3 are a child of file2. So files 3,4,5 should have file2 as a value.